# Decode/encode Java

Tags: java, security, decode, encode

My problem is revert operation encode .

```
String computedLtpaTokenMd5 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(ltpaToken.getBytes())));
```

how to recover the token `ltpaToken` by `computedLtPaTOkenMD5`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

That is the whole point of a cryptographic hash function (which MD5 is, or rather was, you should not use it anymore): It is one-way.

All you can do is check if a given token matches that hashed value (by running the same hash function again and either getting the same output or not).

---

(You can reverse the Base64 *encoding*, but not the MD5 *hashing*)